# Not able to click a button which is not enabled using Appium Java for Android app

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I have to create a transfer. When I run the script the 'Transfer' button for which 'enabled' is false therefore script not able to tap 'Transfer' button & fails. I have attached a screen shot of uiautomator viewer dump.[image]

The workaround I found is to manually click on amount edit box and then this enables the on-screen android keyboard and by entering value manually for 'amount' field & then 'Transfer' button got enabled & can be clicked. But I am not sure how to enter value in edit box from on-screen android keyboard and then get rid of this keyboard to enter date & press 'Transfer' button. [image]

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So if I got Your question right? You are not able to hide keyboard and interact with "Transfer" button? and input date in Date field?

Comment: My basic concern is to hit 'Transfer' button. Since it is not enabled as I stated in question, then I tried the workaround but it require values to be entered in 'Amount' field via android/virtual on-screen keyboard and then hiding the keyboard. I hope you got my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem. My approach is to first click on 'Amount' field and then do sendkeys the value of amount. For details see below code:-

```
    //locating the amount field using xpath
    MobileElement amount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='com.abc.rbanking:id/workflow_step_amount_value']"));

    amount.click();

    amount.sendKeys("1.25");
   //clicking and sendkeys would enable the disabled 'Transfer' button

   //locating the 'Date' field and click it. Clicking it would get rid of soft android keyboard
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text = 'Date']")).click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("com.abc.rbanking:id/back_button")).click();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='com.abc.rbanking:id/PrimaryButton' and @text='Transfer']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

First set following capabilities:

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```

second try to hide keyboard on following way:

```
driver.hideKeyboard(); // doesn't work on newer versions of appium
```

or try this:

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);  //this also doesn't work on all devices but give it a try
```

For date control I'm not quite sure which control You're using date-picker or some custom date control, but on each action try to hide keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Kovacic for your efforts. Before applying your solution, I would like to know whether Appium supports entering of value from android/virtual on-screen keyboard in an edit box for example 'amount' in my case. This is important because 'Transfer' button will get enabled only when we enter value in amount field from android/virtual on-screen keyboard .

Comment: Can't quiet say its pretty specific, I should also have to test it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can hide the soft keyboard by using following code snippet. It works for me.

```
public void someMethod(){
driver.getKeyboard();
        try {
            if (checkSoftKeyboard())
                driver.hideKeyboard();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public boolean checkSoftKeyboard() throws IOException {
        boolean isKeyboardPresent = false;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInputShown");
        BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String outputText = "";

        while ((outputText = in.readLine()) != null) {

            if(!outputText.trim().equals("")){
                String keyboardProperties[]=outputText.split(" ");
                String keyValue[]=keyboardProperties[keyboardProperties.length-1].split("=");

                String softkeyboardpresenseValue=keyValue[keyValue.length-1];
                if(softkeyboardpresenseValue.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                    isKeyboardPresent=false;
                }else{
                    isKeyboardPresent=true;
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
        return isKeyboardPresent;
    }
```

The **checkSoftKeyboard** method will check if the soft keyboard is already there or not? If it is there it will simply hide the soft keyboard. And then you will be able to see the **Transfer** button.

hope this works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Suraj for your efforts. But it seems you didn't read my complete question. 'Transfer' button is not enabled. In order to make this button enabled user have to enter value for amount field using soft keyboard & then have to hide this keyboard. So this query can be solved 2 ways - either (1) we enable the 'Transfer' button or (2) we know how to enter values from soft keyboard and then hide the keyboard.

Comment: So in order to achieve this what you can do is, you can locate the Enter an Amount field and do a sendkeys any amount you wish and then you can hide the soft keyboard. Thanks!

Comment: I am already doing this but of no use. When I do sendkeys for amount, the 'Transfer' button remain disabled. It get enabled only when user enter amount via soft keyboard. Thanks

Comment: driver.getkeyboard() is the method which will get the softkeyboard. but sometimes it does not work for latest android versions.